# Multithread filling of an array in IOS

Tags: ios, arrays, multithreading

I have a method that fills in an array, but the calculation inside is pretty big and slow, and I would like to use multithreading in the hope of speeding it up.

```
unsigned char array[500*500*4];
for(int i=0; i<500; i++) {
    for(int j=0; j<500; j++) {

        CGFloat element = [self veryLongCalculationWithI:i andJ:j];

        array[k] = drand48()*255; 
        array[k+1] = drand48()*255; 
        array[k+2] = drand48()*255;
        array[k+3] = element*255; 
        k+=4;
    }
}
```

How would I do that ? I've been looking into GDC with dispatch async, but I'm not sure if that's the best way of doing it. Any advice ?

Comment: have you tried anything yet?

Comment: are you looking for a way to execute the entire calculation in one different thread other than the main thread - OR - are you looking for a way to split the calculation itself over multiple threads?

Comment: I want to split the calculation itself.

Answer (score 0):

One solution to help parallelize the calculations would be to use a concurrent `NSOperationQueue`.

```
NSOperationQueue *queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
// Be sure to call free() on array when appropriate
unsigned char *array = calloc(500 * 500 * 4, sizeof(unsigned char));
int k = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < 500; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 500; j++) {
        [queue addOperationWithBlock:^{
            CGFloat element = [self veryLongCalculationWithI:i andJ:j];
            array[k + 3] = element * 255;
        }];

        [queue addOperationWithBlock:^{
            array[k] = drand48() * 255; 
            array[k + 1] = drand48() * 255; 
            array[k + 2] = drand48() * 255;
        }];

        k += 4;
    }
}

// optional, if needed:
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0), ^{
    [queue waitUntilAllOperationsAreFinished];

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(). ^{
        // Update UI as needed
    });
});
```

The above is one possible way to break it down. Try a few variations and do some timing tests. Also keep in mind that the results will depend on the device and how many cores it has.

Update - the above code ends up creating 500,000 operations. That overhead may be worse than the original code. Try something like this:

```
NSOperationQueue *queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
// Be sure to call free() on array when appropriate
unsigned char *array = calloc(500 * 500 * 4, sizeof(unsigned char));
int k = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < 500; i++) {
    [queue addOperationWithBlock:^{
        for (int j = 0; j < 500; j++) {
            CGFloat element = [self veryLongCalculationWithI:i andJ:j];
            array[k + 3] = element * 255;

            array[k] = drand48() * 255; 
            array[k + 1] = drand48() * 255; 
            array[k + 2] = drand48() * 255;
            k += 4;
        }
    }];
}

// optional, if needed:
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0), ^{
    [queue waitUntilAllOperationsAreFinished];

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(). ^{
        // Update UI as needed
    });
});
```

Comment: that looks good, but I'm getting cannot refer to declaration with an array type inside block when trying to access array inside the block

Comment: It turns out your can't use a fixed C array in a block. So I updated the code to use a dynamically allocated array. This should work.

Comment: It looks like it's working. How do I know when every block is finished ?

Comment: That's what the `[queue waitUntilAllOperationsAreFinished];` line is for. It won't return until all operations are complete.

Comment: For some reason my original code takes 4 seconds to complete whereas parallel code takes 12. How can this be possible ?

Comment: It could be the overhead of adding 500,000 blocks. Try other approaches such using 1 operation inside the inner block or putting the entire inner loop inside an operation.

Comment: Someone care to explain their down vote? If there is a problem with this answer you can explain what the issue is.

Answer (score -1):

We have a general syntax for GCD in swift.
Do your calculation in background and update the UI in foreground

BASIC SYNTAX

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0)) {
    // do background task
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
        // update some UI
    }
}
```

Keep all your calculation code in background task. This will not block your UI.